# Cannot connect to certain websites on any browser. Tracert and ping both work normally for affected websites

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, browser, internet-connection

I cannot connect to Facebook or Imgur through Chrome, Firefox, or Edge, (I'm running Windows 10). This is on my laptop wifi connection, which I've tested on 4 different wifi connections (home, school, friends wifi, and work). I can ping and tracert these websites just fine:
[Example Tracert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqpqK.jpg)

I've already tried adjusting any proxy settings and setting DNS preferences for my wifi card but it doesn't seem to help. This is an ipconfig of my wifi card: [Wifi card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOBv9.jpg) (I can't actually view these imgur links since Imgur doesn't work on my laptop.)

I've also tried flushing my DNS as well as running both SFC/SCANNOW and dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth to no avail.

Comment: Disable all antivirus, VPN, or other protection products and try again. If that doesn't work, boot into safe mode (with network support) and attempt to connect again.

Comment: What country are you in - perhaps these sites are blocked?  Can you access them with other devices - a different PC or phone for example?

Comment: What is the error you are getting when the website fails? Can you confirm your date & time is correctly set as I've seen that cause security/websites issues. Does the location/network your at require proxy? Are you using that to bypass some website blocking?

Comment: I'm in the United States (Virginia) and I've tried networks with Comcast, Verizon, and whatever Virginia Tech uses for their provider. I can access those websites fine with my phone, and any other laptop or desktop computer connected to those same networks. I do not run any antivirus or firewall other than the ones that ship with Windows 10 by default (already deleted malwarebytes completely). I am not using any proxy right now and have made sure that my date and time are set up correctly (matches all other devices on the network.). I will boot into safe mode with network support to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've done some basic troubleshooting already, let's do a bit more.

1. You said you checked your proxy settings but please double check that the proxy settings for your browser are set to use the system-wide option and that the system wide setting is set to automatic.
2. Check the hostfile on your system to ensure someone/thing has not messed with your local DNS resolution. The file c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts should not contain any references to the affected websites.
3. Ensure that there are no add-ons running in the browsers. Try running each browser in compatibility mode to confirm no malicious or misconfigured add-ons.
4. Try an alternate tool such as powershell or notepad to see if you can connect to the sites. Sounds crazy? Open Notepad, click open and type https://imgur.com into the file box and click open. You can also use powershell `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://imgur.com`. If these work, something malicious is most likely on your machine blocking the browsers.
5. Confirm that you do not have an web protection software installed on your machine. Family filters and security software can interfere with your internet browsing.
6. Try using a VPN or proxy to filter your traffic. You could use Hamachi to another computer or try a free VPN service to confirm if the issue is your local internet.
7. Try booting your computer to an alternate OS. Ubuntu, Knoppix and several other OS have Live CDs that you can boot from which will rule out malicious software on your machine. If this works, try re-installing your OS.

Comment: I tried your fourth suggestion of using powershell. It seems that imgur and facebook work through powershell (it says StatusDescription OK and seems to display some html). Does this mean that there is something malicious on my computer blocking only facebook and imgur?

Comment: It means your machine is able to connect to the websites but somehow the browsers are being blocked. Usually this would be a proxy issue, add-on, or other software interfering with the browser. Did you try the 'safe mode' for your browser? Also, what does the browser show when trying to access the sites?

Comment: I just saw another question where ESET NOD was responsible for blocking the browser. Do you have an antivirus software with web filtering installed?

Comment: No I have no antivirus software other than the default windows defender antivirus and firewalls. I just tried safe mode on chrome (disabling all extensions) and it still gives me the same results. Imgur.com takes too long to respond while Facebook.com has the connection reset.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome. Sounds like something has gone very wrong with your system, possibly a virus. You may need to reinstall Windows. There's a "refresh" option in Windows 10 that will wipe away most things.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Chrome and Firefox. I've scanned my computer with the basic windows defender that comes with Windows 10 and have installed, scanned, then uninstalled with the free version of malwarebytes (and both found nothing suspicious). I will try refreshing Windows 10 later on after I try booting into safe mode with networking support and seeing if that works.